Functor from Linear Operators to Characteristic Polynomials
I was wondering if there was any cool category theory relating to characteristic polynomials.
We can map linear transformations to their characteristic polynomials, but we of course can't map vector spaces to anything reasonable. So maybe we need a category where the linear transformations are the objects? I'm assuming something already exists for this or there's a very reasonable answer to why it doesn't exist.

Why do you think there should be anything? The characteristic polynomial is not even defined for all linear endomorphisms, let alone linear maps between different vector spaces. (What is the characteristic polynomial of the left shift operator on the vector space of sequences?)

It's defined for maps on a finite dimensional vector space. I see what you're saying about it needing to be the same vector space, however.

I just thought it might exist since "everything is a category" is one motto of category theory, so maybe there's some clever way of expressing this in category theoretic language.
